# ListAgg Over ListAgg - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to get some data from multiple rows under same column (SRAV.XYZ) and concat it with other col hence used the listagg query.

```
SELECT LISTAGG (
 REGEXP_SUBSTR (SRAV.XYZ,
    '[^:]+$'),
   ';')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY
REGEXP_SUBSTR (
SRAV.XYZ,
'[^:]+$')) ||';'||SRA.ABC
  /*(CASE
      WHEN SRA.ABC like 'PROF.TMP' THEN SRA.ABC = 'TMP'
      WHEN SRA.ABC like 'PROF' THEN SRA.ABC ='PROF'
      ELSE SRA.ABC='EMPLOYEES' END) */
FROM TEST1 SPAEM,
     TEST2 SRAV,
     TEST3  srm,
     TEST4  SRA
       WHERE SRAV.RID = srm.RGID
         AND SRAV.PID IN
              ('123RTU23',
               '456U43',
               'AB4577Y')
        AND SRAV.XYZ IS NOT NULL
        AND SPAEM.EMPID = srm.SEC_UUID
        AND SRAV.PID = SRA.PRID
        AND SPAEM.EMPID = 139806
        group by ABC
```

I am able to get the output in the below format:

```
  physics;PROF.TMP
  bio;EMPLOYEES
```

Now, I am having 2 issues that I am unable to handle.

1. I want the output in the below format:

   ```
   physics;PROF.TMP,bio;EMPLOYEES
   ```
2. My case when is not working ( hence commented ) when I am trying to concat.

The ideal output would be:

```
   physics;TMP,bio;EMPLOYEES
```

Any help in this regard.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` probably doesn't work because of `LIKE`; the way you put it, it acts as if it was `=`, actually. Wildcards are missing. Also, syntax you used seems to be wrong (from my point of view). Perhaps you meant to say something like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN SRA.ABC like '%PROF.TMP%'   THEN 'TMP'
  WHEN SRA.ABC like '%PROF%'       THEN 'PROF'
  ELSE 'EMPLOYEES' 
END
```

---

As of `listagg` over `listagg`: use your current query as a **subquery** or as a CTE, and then apply yet another `listagg`:

```
with your_current_query as
  (select listagg(...) within group over (...) as result_1
   from ...
   where ...
  )
-- apply listagg to result_1
select listagg(result_1, ', ') over (...) as final_result
from your_current_query
```

---

That's *theory*. If you want something more, provide a simple test case.

Comment: Case suggestion worked like charm . was able to fix . Working on other suggestion